# A simple question about for loops in dictionaries and lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

guys. Can you explain to me where can I find information about for loops in lists and dictionaries like this:

friendships = {i["id"]: ['Joe'] for i in users}

When I try to search in the Google "for loops in lists and dictionaries" it just gives me sites where information is only about a normal for loop like this:

for i in x:
et cetera

I hope you'll help me :)

Comment: They are called "list comprehensions" and "dict comprehensions".

Comment: On docs.python.org I found about [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-12) in less than a minute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "list comprehension" and similar mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-and-similar-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i)

Comment: @destructioneer Yes, it can be found in the documentation - if one knows what to search for. On the other hand the explanation for [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is in one of the first chapters of the tutorial.

Comment: This is a dictionary comprehension. The value of *friendships* will depend on what *users* refers to. Unfortunately you haven't shown *users* or your expected output

Comment: @Matthias I was searching for `for`, and found a reference for the statement and one for the comprehension.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe you have something wrong with `users` list:

input: `{ i['ID'] : 'JOE' for i in [{'ID':1},{'ID':2}]}`

output: `{1: 'JOE', 2: 'JOE'}`

It is called [dictionary comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

Comment: @JohnyCapo - No - this is a dictionary comprehension

Comment: Yes, my bad, but still answers the issue here.